# How could we use selenium and webdriver in python to grab all the product names, prices and ratings? Say we are on amazon page of bestsellers books

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

I am mostly confused with whether using `find_elements_by_name` or `find_elements_by_tag` in certain circumstances.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at [tour] and read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you have this code on an HTML web page:
[image: HTML code image]
If you're trying to click the checkbox. You'd use something like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_name('communitymode').click()
```

We got the name `communitymode` from `name="communitymode"` in the HTML code.